# How to suppress Click event on <tr> when clicking on the button on the <tr>?

Tags: jquery

I have a click event on the table row that executes an action. However when I click on the button on the same row, I would like to prevent the on-row-click event and simply do what the button does, and I don't know how to achieve this.

I have created a --> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/VhYdD/2/) <-- to demonstrate this. Simply click on a table row and you see a button appearing. Then click on the button. You will see that the row-click-event executed again, while clicking on the button. How do I prevent this?

```
 <table id="tab_open_deals" class="table table-condensed table-striped cb_table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="search_result">
    <tr>
      <td><a class="btn my_btn hidden2" href="#">Button</a></td>
      <td>39.90</td>
      <td>29 Dec 2012</td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="btn my_btn hidden2" href="#">Button</a></td>
    <td>1499.00</td>
    <td>8 Jan 2013</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hidden2{
    display: none;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab_open_deals tbody tr').off('click').on('click', function() {
        var row = $('<tr/>');
        row.load('/echo/html/', {
            html: '<td class="override" colspan="4"><table class="table-striped sub_table-hover"><thead><tr><th>Sub1</th><th>Sub2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></td>'
        });

        row.insertAfter($(this));
      $(this).find(".my_btn").off('click').on('click', function(){ alert("clicked") })
        $(this).find(".my_btn").show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this to stop the propagation event

```
       event.stopPropagation();
```

see here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/houmie/VhYdD/2/)

Comment: ahh of course. I like this, its clean. FYI, your link is bad, you haven't updated your solution. But I got your idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a `return false;` in the `click`

```
$(this).find(".my_btn").off('click').on('click', function () {
  alert("clicked");
  return false;
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VhYdD/4/

Comment: Yeah that would work. Many thanks. Only thing is that `return false` does three things at the same time, it seems `event.stopPropagation()` is the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the click behavior from the TR that that button resides. You can use a jQuery method like `$(this).closest('tr')` we can search up from the button through the DOM to find the TR, alternatively you could find the parent using parent functions in jQuery. Once we find the element (TR) we are looking for we can `unbind` the click function from it.

So your final call would look like this:

```
$(this).closest('tr').unbind('click');
```

I've inserted this into your code and it works as expected, removing the click event from the TR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tab_open_deals tbody tr').on('click', function() {
        var row = $('<tr/>');
        row.load('/echo/html/', {
        html: '<td class="override" colspan="4"><table class="table-striped sub_table-hover"><thead><tr><th>Sub1</th><th>Sub2</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></td>'
    });
  $(this).find(".my_btn").on('click', function(){
       $(this).closest('tr').unbind('click');
       alert("clicked") })
       $(this).find(".my_btn").show();
       row.insertAfter($(this));
    });
});
```

I hope this works well for you.