# C# MVC Deactivate (Disable) table row on click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a table whose values are looped in and a button in each row that I am attempting to use to deactivate that row if clicked:

```
        <table id="categoryList" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.id</td>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default pull-left" id="btn-deactivate">Deactivate</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The rows are clickable at this point due to this javascript:

```
$("#categoryList > tbody > tr").click(function (event) {

    $("#categoryModal #categoryId").val($(event.target).parent().children()[0].innerText);
    $("#categoryModal #categoryName").val($(event.target).parent().children()[1].innerText);

    $("#categoryModal .deleteButton").attr("href", $("#colDelUrl").val() + "?categoryId=" + $(event.target).parent().children()[0].innerText);
    $("#categoryModal .deleteButton").show();

    $("#categoryModal").modal({ show: true, backdrop: true });
});
```

The goal is to have the button deactivate (disable so it won't be clickable) the selected row when clicked and then reactivate the row on the second click.

Comment: What do you mean by deactivating the row?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. You don't have a button (only a link)

Comment: The same thing as disabling a button: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

Comment: @CavanFlynn, yeah but you don't have anything to deactivate in your row. It's just a row with which you already can't interact

Comment: Its not the same - you don't have any `<button>` elements - its and `<a>` element (which does not have a `disabled' property)

Comment: Since you are not using `btn-deactivate` as anchor, you could replace it as button, then you can disable using `disabled` property .

Comment: Sorry, I was a little unclear with my explanation. I changed the link to a button and added the javascript that makes a row clickable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to suppress Click event on <tr> when clicking on the button on the <tr>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171571/how-to-suppress-click-event-on-tr-when-clicking-on-the-button-on-the-tr)

Answer (score 0):

Add active class at table rows.

```
      <table id="categoryList" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
        {
            <tr class="active">
                <td>@item.id</td>
                <td>@item.name</td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-default pull-left" id="btn-deactivate">Deactivate</button></td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

make click on row active only if row has class="active":

```
$("#categoryList > tbody > tr.active").click(function (event) {

    $("#categoryModal #categoryId").val($(event.target).parent().children()[0].innerText);
    $("#categoryModal #categoryName").val($(event.target).parent().children()[1].innerText);

    $("#categoryModal .deleteButton").attr("href", $("#colDelUrl").val() + "?categoryId=" + $(event.target).parent().children()[0].innerText);
    $("#categoryModal .deleteButton").show();

    $("#categoryModal").modal({ show: true, backdrop: true });
});
```

siwitch on/off click on rows by changing tr class:

```
$("#btn-deactivate").click(event)
{
  var target = $( event.currentTarget );
      var targetRow= target.closest( 'tr' );
 if (targetRow.hasClass( "active" ))
 { 
     targetRow.removeClass( "active" ).addClass( "inactive" );
 }
 else
 {
     targetRow.removeClass( "inactive" ).addClass( "active" );
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, something is missing. The selected table row is still clickable and brings up the modal. I'm trying to sort through it and figure out whats going on.

Comment: There's got to be something I'm missing on my end. Your solution should work. Thank you