# Prevent button click from triggering click on tr while keeping Clipboard.js intact

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard.js

I have a table with rows. In each row there is a "copy to clipboard" button implemented using [Clipboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

Now I want the table row to be clickable and I want it to redirect to "google.com", if the user clicks anywhere on the row BUT the button. 
When the user clicks the button, I want to copy the text to the clipboard, but NOT redirect.

I have tried using the solution [suggested in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171571/how-to-suppress-click-event-on-tr-when-clicking-on-the-button-on-the-tr), but using `event.stopPropagation()` also disables the Clipboard.js functionality.

Is there an elegant solution for this problem? Here's some code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='valign-middle' data-href='www.google.com'>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td>
            <button data-clipboard-text='www.facebook.com' id='clipboard-btn'>
            <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    // activate Clipboard buttons
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('button#clipboard-btn');

    // make table rows clickable
    $(function(){
        $('.table tr[data-href]').each(function(){
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
                function(){ 
                    $(this).addClass('active'); 
                },  
                function(){ 
                    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
                }).click( function(event){
                    document.location = $(this).attr('data-href'); 
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a class for **td** in **tr** except for the last one in which your copy button is present, then instead of applying click event on row you can have this click event on each **td** and then check in click event whether **td** has that specified class or not, if it has redirect it to google.com else do nothing.

Below is the sample implementation :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='valign-middle' data-href='www.google.com'>
        <td class='normalText'>Text</td>
        <td>
            <button data-clipboard-text='www.facebook.com' id='clipboard-btn'>Copy
            <i class="fa fa-clipboard"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
 var clipboard = new Clipboard('button#clipboard-btn');

    // make table rows clickable
    (function(){
        $('table tr[data-href] td').each(function(){
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer').hover(
                function(){ 
                    $(this).addClass('active'); 
                },  
                function(){ 
                    $(this).removeClass('active'); 
                });
                $(this).click( function(event){
                    if($(this).hasClass("normalText"))
                    document.location = $(this).parent().attr('data-href'); 
                }
            );
        });
    });
</script>
```